# chain populating select with woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress

My special form has two select boxes. I got the first one populate with options from a product categories

What I'm trying to achieve next is the following:

By selecting one of the category from first pre-populated  box - the second  box gets populated with sub categories for selected category on what option was selected in the first  box.

and By selecting one of the category from second   box - the third box gets populated with  for The product belongs to that subcategory.

Comment: What did you try yourself to solve this problem?

Comment: I did not find the way to do this .. Is there a way or a plugins to implement this idea?